# When unit testing my app with SendBird, is it possible to have 2 separate user connections, to the OpenChannel for example

Tags: sendbird

In my unit test, the App is started (which creates a connection with a user, say User1) and my unit test then creates a separate connection with User2 but it seems like this disconnects the first user connection.

Basically, I want to test the messaging using an OpenChannel.

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Comment: Ended up using 2 emulator instances as I was unable to workaround the limitation.  I have since switched to Firebase as well.